# Angular búsqueda sensitiva con base de datos

Tags: html, angular

Necesito un ejemplo de una búsqueda sensitiva y que los datos encontrados se muestren en una tabla,  que traiga datos de una base de datos y sea en html, para poder agregarlo a una tabla aparte.
Es como si fuera un carrito de compras en un sistema de ventas, con angularjs, html, servlets.

Comment: Bienvenido a stack overflow en español. Te recomiendo que tomes el [tour] y revises [ask]

Comment: ¿Podrías acotar un poco más tu problema? Recuperar la información de base de datos, recuperar la información del backend desde Angular, pintar una tabla... por el título de tu pregunta, parece que sólo es en el filtrado de los resultados. ¿Con qué estás dibujando esa tabla? Aportando mayor información los usuarios de la comunidad podrán tener más detalle y podrán ayudarte mejor. Gracias!